# How do I add a subdocument in Spring 5 Reactive?

Tags: spring, spring-data, project-reactor

I want to add a subdocument to a document using Spring 5 Reactive.

To do this I will look up my Combat class, then using an array of Strings, which are the IDs, find those specific existing Character documents, and copy their contents into the Combat Document.

The url will look as follows:

```
@PatchMapping("/{combId}/characters/add")
```

I have the following Combat class model:

```
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Document
public class Combat {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String campaignId;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @JsonFormat
            (shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", timezone = "GMT", locale = "en_US")
    private Date dateCreated;
    private Set<Character> playerCharacters = new HashSet<>(); // complete documents of the PCs
    private Set<Pet> pets = new HashSet<>(); // complete documents of the Pets
    private Set<String> monsters = new HashSet<>(); // ids of the monsters
}
```

Along with the Character Model:

```
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Document
public class Character {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String campaignId;
    private String playerId;
    private String photoUrl;
    private Combatant combatant;


}
```

The Combat resource will look as follows:

```
public Mono<Combat> saveCombat(@RequestBody String[] characters, @PathVariable("combId") final String combId) {
    Mono<Combat> combat = combatRepository
            .findById(combId);

    Set<String> characterStringSet = Arrays.stream(characters).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    Flux<Character> characterFlux = characterStringSet.stream()
            .map(characterRepository::findById);
```

I'm pretty new to Reactive and I am just completely stumped on how to make this happen. As you can see I started breaking down into an iterative style of programming because I had no clue. If anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will do what you seek. It takes the character IDs, gets the distinct values, loads each one, collects them into a set, then combines that with the desired combat object, assigned the characters, and then saves the combat and returns it.

```
public Mono<Combat> saveCombat(@RequestBody String[] characterIds, @PathVariable("combId") final String combId) {
    return Flux.fromArray(characterIds)
        .distinct()
        .flatMap(characterRepository::findById)
        .collect(HashSet::new, Set::add)
        .zipWith(combatRepository.findById(combId), (characters, combat) -> {
            combat.setCharacters(characters);
            return combat);
         })
        .flatMap(combatRepository::save);
}
```

Comment: I am having issues with the code you listed. 
1) It is getting the characters variable confused with the one passed into the Controller. That is easy to fix and I did.
2) This statement: combatRepository.findById(combId), (characters, combat)  -> {
        combat.setCharacters(characters);
        return combat);
It doesn't like the setCharacters call. I believe it doesnt understand what type combat is? Not sure.
Cannot resolve symbol 'combat'